# What is a good single word to cover both save and share?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to come up with a word that can be used in a menu in a piece of software where the options include saving to the user's computer, saving to the cloud and sharing on various social media sites.  All the ways the data could persist, only I don't think many of the users would understand "persist."

Comment: *Back Up* should do it.

Comment: I don't think "back up" would cover sharing on social media.

Comment: Is this a drop down menu with the three options, or 'save' sends it to all three? May we have a screen shot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most software that I've seen use "Share" to cover all of those. However, you could use "Options" or "Actions" as a general term.

Answer (score 1):

The word *[store](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/store)* indicates the storage location, from which it will be shared:

> 1.1 Retain or enter (information) for future electronic retrieval:

Answer (score 1):

> Export

Depending on the kind of software, and the kind of stuff being saved/shared, this *might* be appropriate.